# How to hide suggestions of a GWT suggest box?

Tags: javascript, gwt, suggestbox

I want to add the functionality that whenever I press the reset button the suggestion list 
should get hided.
I have tried the hideSuggestionList() method but it is showing as deprecated.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use your own `SuggestionDisplay`, then this should Just Work™:

```
((DefaultSuggestionDisplay) suggestBox.getSuggestionDisplay()).hideSuggestions();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Is suggestBox.setFocus(false) equivalent?

Comment: Focus should switch to your reset button when you click it, so `setFocus(false)` should be useless (and the popup should already close just because of that; it'd be interesting if you could make a small project reproducing the issue). If you think it's a bug, please report it.